# Build native executable with profile information using Ocamlbuild

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, ocamlfind

How to build with enabled profile information using Ocamlbuild? It seems `-p` doesn't work there.

Now, I use `ocamlopt` for this. For example,

```
$ ocamlfind ocamlopt -c -p -thread -package core test.ml
$ ocamlfind ocamlopt -p -o test -thread -package core -linkpkg test.cmx
```

How to do the same with

```
ocamlbuild -user-ocamlfind test.native
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass the argument explicitly,

```
ocamlbuild -cflags -p
```

or in your `_tags` file,

```
true : profile
```

There is also a rule for the file-name,

```
ocamlbuild test.p.native
```

Comment: `ocamlbuild -cflags -p` doesn't work on my machine. This is exactly what I tried to do. It seems `-cflags` is for `ocamlc` only. `test.p.native` and `true : profile` work as expected. Thanks a lot!